# Recover my jobs in Talend

Tags: talend, recovery

I have a problem with my account in windows. It disappeared and I can't find a way to recover it. So I can't access my data on comp and my jobs are not up in the cloud. Is any chance that I can recover my jobs with my talend account? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Talend Open Studio, the source code of your jobs is only stored on your local disk.
With the subscription version of Talend, you would be using a remote repository (svn or git), where your jobs are stored.
With either version, your jobs are never going to be stored outside these locations, so a Talend account is of no use.
You may have a chance with a data recovery software to restore the files from disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to make a recovery and then come back with an answer.

Comment: So, I could access my workspace after recovery and then imported in my new Talend Studio. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm glad you could recover your jobs :)

Answer (score 0):

if your disk (hdd) not encrypted you still can connect the disk to another computer and read your data.

Comment: I can't do that either.... I was wondering if there can be access to jobs via talend account.